# I need to know if there is any other way to use sql command line without cmd

Tags: mysql, cmd

Do i need to go to cmd and execute "mysql -u root -p" command first ,to execute mysql commands. Isn't there any direct method to use sql commands on mysql.

Comment: You can use third party applications like **MySQL Workbench** and **SQLyog**

Comment: Create a shortcut for the command. Starting it does not need in separate CMD execution. Moreover, if your commands batch is saved as a file you can drag it over this shortcut for to execute the batch and then look for the output in tee file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using **MySQL Workbench** for executing sql commands instead of cmd. In the latest versions of mysql installer, MySQL Workbench exists by default. So you can also try to upgrade your sql version. You can download latest version as per your os by this link: [download](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/)

Answer (score 0):

there is many SQL tool for this, sharing you a blog please consider for the best choice.

https://www.guru99.com/top-20-sql-management-tools.html